# CSV and html as one of the column

Tags: vb.net, filehelpers

Have csv create but FileHelpers library (but don;t think its important here. However my csv is comma delimeted file. I always make quotes between each field. In my last column i am pulling html code. However when trying to open csv in excel part of my html field column data is going to first column and some data from html is placed in B column in excel Can someone help here and tell me what's wrong? Here's exact example:

[Sample csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kkr3j99d5nxq24/example.csv?dl=0)

```
Artikelnummer,Vater,Variation1,Variationswert1,Variation2,Variationswert2,Variation3,Variationswert3,Barcode,Artikelname,Artikelname2,Hersteller,KategorieLevel1,KategorieLevel2,KategorieLevel3,KategorieLevel4,KategorieLevel5,Merkmalname1,Merkmalwertname1,Merkmalname2,Merkmalwertname2,Merkmalname3,Merkmalwertname3,Html
"29.1023.1","","Height","WeiB","","","","","","","","","","Kategoria_A","Podkategoria_A","","co tu?","Height","WeiB","","","","","<meta http-equiv=""content-type"" content=""application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8""/>

<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Überblick:
</b>
<br>

</br>
<table cellpadding=""10"" cellspacing=""10"" align=""left"" style=""font-size:12pt;table-layout:fixed;width:30%;"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Marke:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">JUSThome
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Serie:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">blabla
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Artikel-Nr.:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">29.1023.1
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Height:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">Zur auswahl
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Material:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">Material_B1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><table cellpadding=""10"" cellspacing=""10"" align=""right"" style=""font-size:12pt;table-layout:fixed;width:70%;"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Abmessungen:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;""></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Höhe:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">1,00 cm
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Breite:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">2,00 cm
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><div style=""clear:both !important;"">

</div>


<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Abmessungen im Detail:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Höhe: 1,00 cm</li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Breite: 2,00 cm</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Kot : kott </li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Swinia : swiania </li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Sekcja_A:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">WK</li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">ZW</li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Sekcja_Design:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">NF</li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
"
"29.1023.2","","Height","WeiB","","","","","","","","","","Kategoria_A","Podkategoria_A","","co tu?","Height","WeiB","","","","","<meta http-equiv=""content-type"" content=""application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8""/>

<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Überblick:
</b>
<br>

</br>
<table cellpadding=""10"" cellspacing=""10"" align=""left"" style=""font-size:12pt;table-layout:fixed;width:30%;"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Marke:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">JUSThome
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Serie:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">blabla
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Artikel-Nr.:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">29.1023.2
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Height:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">WeiB
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Material:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">Material_B1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><table cellpadding=""10"" cellspacing=""10"" align=""right"" style=""font-size:12pt;table-layout:fixed;width:70%;"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Abmessungen:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;""></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Höhe:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">1,00 cm
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Breite:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">2,00 cm
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><div style=""clear:both !important;"">

</div>


<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Abmessungen im Detail:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Höhe: 1,00 cm</li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Breite: 2,00 cm</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Kot : kott </li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Swinia : swiania </li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Sekcja_A:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">WK</li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">ZW</li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Sekcja_Design:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">NF</li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
"
"29.1023.3","","Height","WeiB","","","","","","","","","","Kategoria_A","Podkategoria_A","","co tu?","Height","WeiB","","","","","<meta http-equiv=""content-type"" content=""application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8""/>

<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Überblick:
</b>
<br>

</br>
<table cellpadding=""10"" cellspacing=""10"" align=""left"" style=""font-size:12pt;table-layout:fixed;width:30%;"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Marke:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">JUSThome
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Serie:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">blabla
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Artikel-Nr.:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">29.1023.3
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Height:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">WeiB
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""40%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Material:</td><td width=""60%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">Material_B1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><table cellpadding=""10"" cellspacing=""10"" align=""right"" style=""font-size:12pt;table-layout:fixed;width:70%;"">
    <tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Abmessungen:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;""></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Höhe:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">1,00 cm
        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td width=""20%"" border=""3"" style=""vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;color:white;background-color: #b4b4b4"">Breite:</td><td width=""80%"" border=""3"" style=""text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"">2,00 cm
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><div style=""clear:both !important;"">

</div>


<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Abmessungen im Detail:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Höhe: 1,00 cm</li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Breite: 2,00 cm</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Kot : kott </li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">Swinia : swiania </li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Sekcja_A:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">WK</li><li style=""font-size:12pt;"">ZW</li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
<b style=""font-size:22pt;"">Sekcja_Design:
</b>
<ul>
    <li style=""font-size:12pt;"">NF</li>
</ul>

<br>

</br>
"
```

This how it looks like in excel. Every data is placed correctly without html part:
[image]

That's how it looks like when i open it in excel without any modification (before text to columns option):

[image]

Comment: Your html also contains comma's.

Comment: @Natrium i know, therefore i used double quotes for each field. FileHelpers library should do the trick but looks not i used all of available QuoteMode's but seems not working as it should.

Comment: Your CSV looks fine, I can open this as a .csv file in Excel (2016 on Win7) without the HTML ending up in the next row. How exactly are you importing it? It looks like something has split your cell content on semicolons at import time. Don't know why, that is not a standard in CSV handling.

Comment: @bobince so for you it also works when you open in excel? Look at main post i show how it looks like in excel when i open it without any change

Comment: @JimmyJimm: exactly how are you opening it? I am doing right click .csv file in Explorer, Open With -> Excel. If you are doing something different (and I expect you are, since you mention a “text to columns option” that I don't see at all), what is it?

Comment: @bobince i did the same but same behaviour.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem by saving the file in Notepad with Encoding: Unicode, but seemed fine when saved with any other encoding.

Comment: so what could be the problem here?

Comment: @JimmyJimm as I said the encoding. If the file is saved with Unicode encoding it's 20 KB, but when saved with ASCII/ANSI/UTF-8 encoding it's 10 KB and opens fine.

Comment: @Slai as i see after opened in notepad++ its ascii...? My customer from Poland i would need to explain him to change his regional settings to US to open it correctly in excel? Is there any other way to keep regionals and save it to be correctly opened in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine on Excel 2013. See the screen shot. I just saved the content in .csv file and opened in excel.
[image]

Comment: seems it wors for everyone except me. Do you know maybe there is any option in excel i could enabled so i see wrong result?

Comment: I am not sure but you can have look to Excel options i.e. File menu -> Options

Comment: was looking for it but cannot find any appropiate option to it

Comment: Not sure it will work but you can give a try. Open the csv file in notepad or notepad++. Delete the first and last double quotes for the html column. Then manually type them again from keyboard. Save the file and open in excel.

Comment: not works, now i am completly lot what can ido with this

Comment: Please provide the csv file. May be you can provide only top 2 rows in the file.

Comment: I gave a try but in vain. Not sure why it fails only on your system. Even dropbox shows it correctly.

Comment: for me and other friend we have the same problem

Comment: Just in case it works, what regional language settings do u have on your machine? Mine is US English.

Comment: My regional settings is for Poland region (Europe). What i did was to switch to US and miracle ! - It works. However why this happends what's the diffrence?

Comment: Gr8 !!! Research about localization on internet you will get the answer. I hope now you can mark it as answered/solved.

Comment: was looking for but still cant get appropiate answer, can you say in couple words why is that? Previously when i opened it i could specyfi separator how the file has to be traded in option "Text to columns" so this should be enough to sat excel how it is but not worked. Why is that?

Comment: Many applications inherit regional settings. Excel too do this. e.g. Currency and decimal point. Hence I thought it could be regional settings and ask you to give a try. You need to compare regional settings (Poland vs US Eng), which filed is using double quotes or comma. May be its "List Seperator" under Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not technically an answer I was going to put this as a comment to your question.  However, my "reputation" isn't high enough to comment.  Ironic that I can answer questions, but not comment on them.  Anyway...I copied and pasted your example on my Macbook and saved it as CSV.  It opened in Excel fine for me.  I have a feeling it's got something to do with the way newlines are treated by Mac vs. PC.  Wish I could be more help, but since it opens fine for me I can't really troubleshoot the problem.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGCLy.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEkJN.png)

Comment: so you mean for you you see all html contents in the last column correctly? Can you show screenshoot of that?

Comment: I attached screenshots to my original "answer"

Comment: to be honest i am confused then ;/